# uiautomator dump in Runtime.getRuntime().exec() not working

Tags: android, runtime.exec, android-uiautomator

When I put this line in my test app, 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator dump")`, no .xml file was dumped. I am pretty sure I checked the correct location.

I tried to debug my app by putting a break point. When it reaches the break point, I `adb shell` on terminal to get into the device, and then manually run `uiautomator dump` from terminal, then it says `killed`, no .xml file was produced either.

`adb shell uiautomator dump` only produces .xml file when I killed my app, and run this command from terminal.

Is this a sort of permission or accessibility problem?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. making sure to break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like a path with spaces in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `adb shell uiautomator dump` while a test is running.

You can call [UiDevice.dumpWindowHierarchy(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#dumpWindowHierarchy(java.io.File)) from inside your test instead.

Comment: Why we cannot use adb shell uiautomator dump while a test is running?

Comment: There's a limitation in the framework - only one UiAutomation client can be connected at a time. When your test is running, it has the connection. This  prevents `uiautomator dump` from connecting.

Comment: This really helps. Thanks for explanation!